# Floating css footer in IE8

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

Hi this question might be asked a few times, but I can't find a specific example for what I'm doing, I have a footer:

```
<div id="Footer">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span>Copyright</span> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblVersion"></asp:Label> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>     
    </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
div#Footer
{
  padding: 4px 1px 1px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top:80px; 
  border-top: thin solid #000000;
  height:1.5em;
  background-color:#333333;
  color:White;
}
```

In IE6 this worked fine, in IE8 in resolutions of 1280 x 1024 and above this works fine, but below this resolution or when the IE window is made smaller, the footer floats, I've tried setting position/float/clear/display style settings with no luck, does anyone have any ideas how to make this stick at the bottom in smaller screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

read this :

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: It says No content can be outside of the .wrapper and .footer div tags unless it is absolutely positioned with CSS. How do I do this? I have other content outside the footer, and when this other content has its styling set to position:absolute, I still get the same floating problem with the footer

Comment: why do you nned content outside the wrapper or footer?..
what do you need more on the screen?

Comment: its like this <div><div wrapper/><div footer/></div> so what do I need to set on the wrapper?